# How to use For-Each loop on my own collection?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, foreach

I have a Network class, in it `NET` = `ArrayList<Node>`. 
I'm using the Network class to control what can and cannot be added, maintaining the `ArrayList` sorted etc, I have a get method that takes a Node number as argument  that uses binary search over the `ArrayList` (they're sorted according to that number)

But in most cases when other objects need to call on a node they just need to go through the nodes regardless of their numbers and often not knowing the number altogether.

In `Network` i have

```
public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
        return NET.iterator();
}
```

And things like

```
Iterator<Node> i = net.iterator();
Node n;
while (i.hasNext()) {
    n = i.next();
    // do stuff
}
```

But for

```
for (Node n : net) {

}
```

I get "foreach not applicable to expression type". What else I need to add to Network to use the for-each loop, if possible?

My research on this led me only to topics explaining why would I need a for each, and I think it's relevant in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to implement the [`Iterable<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface so that `foreach` will use your iterator.

Comment: I see, worked, though at first i was caught in a trap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601658/java-how-to-implement-iterable