# How to display items in a linked list in java

Tags: java, list

Hi all im wondering how to display all nodes in a linked list. Heres the code I have so far. The Manager class is supposed to operate the list. The movieNode class creates new list nodes for the movie. I know I have to use other things as well but im just trying to get the first element of the list to display for starters.

```
public class Manager {
    MovieNode head;

    public Manager (){
        head=null;
    }

    public void Add (MovieNode data) {
        if (head==null){
            head=data;
        }
    }
    public void Display () {
        int i=1;
        MovieNode temp=head;
        System.out.println("Displaying Movies");
        while (head!=null) {
            System.out.println(temp.getData().getName());
            head=null;
        }
    }
    }
```

also, the code for the MovieNode class

```
public class MovieNode {
        private Movie data;
        private MovieNode next;

        public MovieNode (){
            data=null;
            next=null;
        }

        public MovieNode (Movie data){
            setData(data);

        }

        public void setData (Movie data){
            this.data=data;
        }
        public Movie getData (){
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is clearly a homework question! You need to add a `toString()` methon in `MovieNode` and call that in your `Display` loop.

Comment: Why not use a LinkedList<MovieNode> and just iterate it w/ iterator() or a for loop?

Comment: can you give me a small example of a to string method?

Comment: @Michael: it could be argued that if OP needs to ask such a question, then he'll learn much more about linked lists by actually writing one than by using one already made ; )

Comment: does your addMovieInorder sorts from a to z?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help you get started. Here are some pointers:

**Manager Class**

- You don’t need an explicit constructor for Manager, as you can initialize the `head` variable in line and you’re not passing any other information to the constructor
- Method names in Java are conventionally camel case and start with lower-case letter
- When you add a new item to the linked list, you can pass in just the `data` and create the node in the add method
- Assuming you don’t need to maintain any special order, you can insert the new item to the head of the list. This saves the time to go through the whole list to find the tail or keeping a reference to the tail.
- To display all the movies, you just need to start with the `head` and check if there is a node `next` in list. If you don’t need to implement this custom method, I would recommend implementing the class as Iterable. A SO discussion on this topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601658/java-how-to-implement-iterable)

**MovieNode Class**

- You only need one constructor that takes the `data` and sets the private variable
- You also need the getter and setter for the `next` variable in order to hold the list structure and iterate through the list
- The `toString()` implementation will allow to print an instance of this class directly, as in `displayAllMovies()` method

**Movie Class**

- This class just holds the `title` of the movie for now, but you can extend it according to your spec.

Here is the code:

```
public class Manager {
    MovieNode head = null;

    public void addMovie(Movie data) {
        MovieNode newNode = new MovieNode(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            newNode.setNext(head);
            head = newNode;
        }
    }

    public void addMovieInOrder(Movie data) {
        MovieNode newNode = new MovieNode(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            MovieNode higher = head;
            MovieNode lower = null;

            // find the right position for newNode
            while(higher != null){
                if(newNode.compareTo(higher) > 0){
                    lower = higher;
                    higher = higher.getNext();
                }
                else break;
            }

            newNode.setNext(higher);
            if(higher == head) head = newNode;  //inserting as head
            else lower.setNext(newNode);
        }
    }

    public void displayAllMovies() {
        MovieNode node = head;

        if (node == null) {
            System.out.println("The list is empty!");
        }

        do {
            System.out.println(node.getData());
            node = node.getNext();
        } while (node != null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        manager.addMovieInOrder(new Movie("ddd"));
        manager.addMovieInOrder(new Movie("ccc"));
        manager.addMovieInOrder(new Movie("aaa"));
        manager.addMovieInOrder(new Movie("bbb"));
        manager.displayAllMovies();
    }
}
```

Movie Node class:

```
public class MovieNode implements Comparable<MovieNode> {
    private Movie data;
    private MovieNode next = null;

    public MovieNode(Movie data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(Movie data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Movie getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setNext(MovieNode node) {
        this.next = node;
    }

    public MovieNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MovieNode otherMovieNode) {
        return data.compareTo(otherMovieNode.getData());
    }
}
```

Movie class:

```
public class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {
    private String title;

    public Movie(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Movie otherMovie) {
        return title.compareTo(otherMovie.title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I run this tho, it doesnt display the movie I added?

Comment: It seems that when I display the list, it always displays as empty even if ive added a movie to it

Comment: @user979616 To display the movie you added, you can print it (the passed 'data' variable) in the 'addMovie' method. Have you tried running the main method in Manager class that I provided -- that simple test case seems to work for me?

Comment: I have another class that just handles user input. But it just calls the add movie method anyhow. I add the movie correctly but when I call the display method, head is getting set to null somehow

Comment: @user979616 Maybe you are re-initializing the Manager class instead of using the one you added the movies to? If it still doesn't work, feel free to post that part of code here too and I can take a look at it.

Comment: Ah thats why. Thanks so much. Is there some way I can alphabetically sort these things in the add method? Im thinking I do a compare of the titles and whichever comes first becomes my head. But for multiple titles, how to I order them?

Comment: @user979616 I've updated the code above. In order to maintain sorted order, it's best to make the 'MovieNode' and 'Movie' classes Comparable. Then we can call the comparison function in 'addMovieInOrder' and find the right position in the list.