# How to generate an Iterator from an array of certain object

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

```
private SomeObject[] all_objs;     

public Iterator<SomeObject> iterator() {
   //
}
```

What is the best way to get an iterator from an array of `SomeObject`?

**EDIT**
So there is no way to generate iterator without using the wrappers like ArrayLists or HashSets ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to Implement Iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601658/java-how-to-implement-iterable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `List` iterator:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public <T> Iterator<T> iterator() {
    List<T> list = (List<T>) Arrays.asList(all_objs);

    return list.iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could write your own class that implements `Iterator<SomeObject>`. Simply implement the methods of the interface. If you don't want the users of the iterator from removing items from the array (since it isn't an ArrayList), then throw an UnsupportedOperationException if this method is called.

Of course if you use an `ArrayList<SomeObject>` then the `iterator()` method would only have to return the iterator from the ArrayList making your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at the code of [java.util.ArrayList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html).  Here is how you should implement it.

```
 T=SomeObject //Your Class

 public YourIterable<T> implements Iterable<T>{
     //**Iterable**  Implementing this interface allows an object 
     //to be the target of the "foreach" statement.
     public Iterator<T> iterator() {

          return new Itr();
      }  

   private class Itr implement Iterator<T> {
      //Complex Implementation - You have to maintain a Cursor to keep track of 
      // which record was accessed
            boolean hasNext() {
                 //Returns true if the iteration has more elements.
            }

            T next() { 
             //Returns the next element in the iteration.
            }  

            void remove() {//Remove 
          }

    }

 }
```