# Generics: Why the implemented collections returns an object instead of the specified type?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement an OrderedMapEntry list with custom MapEntries - as I need a custom solution with Vectors I cannot use a TreeMap(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). I implemented a custom list without any errors, but when I use the `OrderedMapEntries` class in an enhanced for loop it returns an `Object`.

- How can I ensure type safety when using an enhanced for loop? What my implementation is doing wrong in ensuring this type safety?

  ```
  public class OrderedMapEntries<K, V> implements Iterator, Iterable{

      private Vector<MapEntry<K, Vector<V>>> vector;
      private int vectorIndex;  // initializes with -1

      class MapEntry<A, B extends AbstractList<V>> implements Iterator, Iterable{
          // MapEntry implementation

      public void insert(int index, K key, Vector<V> vec){
          MapEntry<K, Vector<V>> mapEntry = new MapEntry<>(key, vec);
          vector.add(index, mapEntry);
      }

      @Override
      public MapEntry<K, Vector<V>> next(){
          vectorIndex++;
          return vector[vectorIndex]; 
      }
  }
  ```

I tried to iterate over the collection with an enhanced for loop, but it fails as next() returns an Object and not my specified element.

```
OrderedMapEntries<Integer, String> ome = new OrderedMapEntries<>();
// I filled it with some test data

for (OrderedMapEntries<Integer, String>.MapEntry<Integer, Vector<String>> entry : ome){
    ; 
    }
```

Comment: Please post a compilable class at least. The type parameter `K` isn't even declared.

Comment: thanks! I oversaw the problem with K when I simplified it for the post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are implementing `Iterable`, a raw type, not `Iterable<K>` or `Iterable<V>`. If you omit type parameter like this, then the signature of [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator()) becomes -

```
Iterator iterator();
```

which returns an `Iterator`, not `Iterator<K>` or `Iterator<V>`, whose [next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) method will have a signature like below -

```
Object next();
```

This is the reason why you are getting `Object` in the enhanced for loop, as it internally calls the `Iterator`'s `next` to get the next element.

You can almost never ensure proper type safety if you use raw types like this. For more information, please check out [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 23 - *Don't use raw types in new code*.

Also, your `OrderedMapEntries` class should only implement `Iterable<E>` (please check out how [ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.iterator%28%29) does this). Implement the `iterator` method in it such that it returns an appropriate `Iterator<E>` to the enhanced for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're implementing the raw types of `Iterator` and `Iterable`.  Firstly, you should **never** implement both of them.  Secondly, if you want to implement one of them, implement the generic type as opposed to the raw type.  Here's an example showing [How to implement iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601658/java-how-to-implement-iterable).