# Error: can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

please help me with my error can't seem to make it work because of that can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable. i want to create a barcode and read it  and add it to the word document

**Update Post** the nodeCollection is from the com.aspose.words.

```
import com.aspose.barcode.*;
import com.aspose.barcoderecognition.BarCodeReadType;
import com.aspose.barcoderecognition.BarCodeReader;
import com.aspose.words.Document;
import com.aspose.words.DocumentBuilder;
import com.aspose.words.ImageType;
import com.aspose.words.NodeCollection;
import com.aspose.words.NodeType;
import com.aspose.words.Shape;

              try
        {
            // Generate barcode image
            BarCodeBuilder builder = new BarCodeBuilder();
            builder.setSymbologyType(Symbology.Code39Standard);
            builder.setCodeText("test-123");
            String strBarCodeImageSave = "img.jpg";
            builder.save(strBarCodeImageSave);

            // Add the image to a Word doc
            Document doc = new Document();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
            docBuilder.insertImage(strBarCodeImageSave);
            String strWordFile = "docout.doc";
            doc.save(strWordFile);

            // Recognition part
            // Extract image from the Word document
            NodeCollection<Shape> shapes = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.SHAPE, true, false);
            int imageIndex = 0;

            for(Shape shape: shapes)
            {   
                if (shape.hasImage())
                {
                    // If this shape is an image, extract image to file
                    String extension = ImageTypeToExtension(shape.getImageData().getImageType());
                    String imageFileName = MessageFormat.format("Image.ExportImages.{0} Out.{1}", imageIndex, extension);
                    String strBarCodeImageExtracted = "" + imageFileName;
                    shape.getImageData().save(strBarCodeImageExtracted);

                    // Recognize barcode from this image
                    BarCodeReader reader = new BarCodeReader((BufferedImage) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(strBarCodeImageExtracted),BarCodeReadType.Code39Standard);
                    while (reader.read())
                    {
                        System.out.println("codetext: " + reader.getCodeText());
                    }
                    imageIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static String ImageTypeToExtension(int imageType) throws Exception
    {
        switch (imageType)
        {
            case ImageType.BMP:
                return "bmp";
            case ImageType.EMF:
                return "emf";
            case ImageType.JPEG:
                return "jpeg";
            case ImageType.PICT:
                return "pict";
            case ImageType.PNG:
                return "png";
            case ImageType.WMF:
                return "wmf";
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown image type.");
        }
    }}
```

Comment: What is NodeCollection?

Comment: @AKS `can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` is a compiler error, not a runtime error. There is no stacktrace.

Comment: Simple: don't use a for-each loop here but rather either a standard for loop or a while loop.

Comment: The error message is correct. The shorthand notation only works for arrays or `Iterable`s. If your class doesn't implement Iterable, explicitly ask it for its iterator and use that; if it doesn't have a `getIterator` or equivalent method, write an explicit loop to fetch its contents.

Comment: `"Update Post the nodeCollection is from the com.aspose.words."` -- then the first thing you should do, before even coming here, is to look up the documentation for this class. This should be a reflex action.

Comment: @Rohan21: `com.aspose.words.Nodecollection` is an instance of `Iterable`. You should construct an iterator object explicitly on the `shapes` object and then use in `for` loop. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume Nodecollection is a com.aspose.words.NodeCollection.

If you want to use the foreach syntax you better do:

```
Node[] shapesArray = shapes.toArray();
for (Node node : shapesArray ){ ...
```

Answer (score 3):

> *Error: can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable*

It clearly says that you should iterate only on objects which are iterable.

In your code you are using

```
NodeCollection<Shape> shapes = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.SHAPE, true, false);
...    
for(Shape shape: shapes)
```

The `for` loop fails unless the `shapes` base class is an instance of a `java.util.Collection` or `java.lang.Iterable`.

Check if `NodeCollection` is a *collection* type class that implemented `java.lang.Iterable`.

---

**Edit**:

> *the nodeCollection is from the com.aspose.words.*

`NodeCollection` implements generic `Iterable` directly, without specifying the type of objects it would be handling. Hence you should explicitly generate the `Iterator` from the `NodeCollection` instance and on that you can iterate.

```
NodeCollection<Shape> shapes = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.SHAPE, true, false);
Iterator<Shape> shapesIterator = shapes.iterator();
...    
// now use the above iterator in for loop, as below
for( Shape shape: shapesIterator )
```

**Refer to** [a similar answer on so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601671/767881)