# i am using Collection Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Tags: java, object, collections

I am trying to solve this error, but for some reason, not able to find the issue to fix it. I am using `Collection` in this code. If anyone can point me out what actually I am missing, I would be a great help.

```
Collection challenges = null;
        Map challengesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        ForgotPasswordManager forgotPwdMgr = new ForgotPasswordManager(platform);
        System.out.println("after ForgotPasswordManager(platform)...before getSecretQuestion()");
        challenges = forgotPwdMgr.getSecretQuestion(userID);
        System.out.println("after getSecretQuestion()...");
        for (Object challenge : challenges) {
            String challengeStr = (String)challenge;
            System.out.println("doGetChallenges()...ChallengeStr = " + challengeStr);
            challengesMap.put(challengeStr.trim(), "");
        }
```

I am getting this error  `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` on line: `for (Object challenge : challenges)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425277/error-can-only-iterate-over-an-array-or-an-instance-of-java-lang-iterable). The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22425341/4660897) explains the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Collection` type referenced here :

```
Collection challenges = null;
```

is not the `java.util.Collection` interface that extends the `Iterable` interface.
Otherwise you would have not this error message  :

> Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

at this line :

```
for (Object challenge : challenges) {
```

You are using probably a custom `Collection` class.

So to solve your problem, make your custom custom `Collection` class implement `Iterable` or more simple : use JDK `java.util.Collection` subclasses.

Comment: can you elaborate little bit more i am little confuse @davidxxx

Comment: Ok. Look at the package of the `Collection` class in your imports. You will see that is not `java.util.Collection`. So it means that you use your own `Collection` class.

Comment: i am using the import.java.util.Collection when i click on  Declared type it brings me to the Collection class  @davidxxx

Comment: I suppose you have a `Collection` class in the package of the actual class that declares this code ?

Comment: i didn't define the Collection class in my code after importing it could that be the reason because i am only using collection on this piece of the code @davidxxx

Comment: thank you so much @davidxxx i just made the little change in my two lines
Collection<String> challenges = null;
   Map<String,String> challengesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();