# generic type parameter

Tags: java, generics

I've defined the following classes

```
public class AbstractManager<E> {

    public E save(E o) {
        // Implementation omitted
    }

    public <T> T getSingleResult(Query query, Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(query.getSingleResult());
    }
}

public class MatchingAlgorithmManagerImpl extends AbstractManager {

    void someMethod() {
        // compiler error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Country"
        Country c = this.getSingleResult(query, Country.class);
    }
}
```

I'm very confused about why I'm getting this compiler error, surely it should be using `Country` as the value for `<T>` whereas it seems to be using `Object`, which I presume is the default for the `<E>` when I don't specify a parametric type.

Even stranger, if I change the subclass definition to `public class MatchingAlgorithmManagerImpl extends AbstractManager<Object>`, the error disappears.

Why does the type I define for `E` have any relevance?

Comment: What does query.getSingleResult() return? You are not seeing the ClassCastException there, right?

Comment: It returns an Object, but I dynamically cast it to `<T>`

Comment: Ah, yeah, also you wrote that it doesn't compile, not that it fails at runtime...

Comment: It does fail to compile, why do you think it fails at runtime?

Comment: If you'd feed the clazz.cast the wrong type it would fail at runtime. But of course it can only fail at runtime once it compiles ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a raw type, the compiler indeed removes all generic types, both those related to the class parameter types (`E` in your case), and those that are not (`T` in your case).

So when you don't parametrise your extension, even your `T` gets erasured (is that a verb?) to `Object`, which explains the error.

Good references can be found from [Non-generic reference to generic class results in non-generic return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449103/non-generic-reference-to-generic-class-results-in-non-generic-return-types)

Comment: This is extremely surprising behaviour and also extremely undesireable. I understand that you should always provide a type parameter for a generic class, but I find it very surprising that `extends AbstractManager` means something different to `extends AbstractManager<Object>`

Comment: @Don: There's a clear separation between raw types (which have no angled brackets and exist for backwards compatibility only) and generic types in Java. They should never be mixed. Always declare your types. I don't think it's a problem at all that `AbstractManager` and `AbstractManager<Object>` are not the same... it _is_ weird, though, that this extends to things like this generic method that don't use the class-level type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your class declaration for AbstractManager contains a generic parameter, but when you are extending that class you are using a raw type, 
try

```
public class MatchingAlgorithmManagerImpl extends AbstractManager<Country>
```

Comment: But surely Country would then be the value supplied for <E>, not <T>? I think you might need to read the question again (no offence meant).